# Getters and Setters for Generics over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, getter-setter

If I have a generic class in a WCF service

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "TestGenericOf{0}")]
public class TestGeneric<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get { return _testProperty.ToUpper(); }
        set { _testProperty = value; }
    }

    private string _testProperty;
}
```

and a client (MVC in this case) consumes the service through a service reference. I'd like to share the getter and setter logic between both the service and the client; however, since the class is generic, the class created on the client is different from that on the service.

```cs
public partial class TestGenericOfstring : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string TestPropertyField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string TestProperty {
        get {
            return this.TestPropertyField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TestPropertyField, value) != true)) {
                this.TestPropertyField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TestProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to go about implementing the same getter, setter logic on both the service and the client?

Comment: It's just a data contract specifying a contract, not explicit behavior. The call to ToUpper() will not be present at the client (unless the client has your classes).

Comment: I believe the call to `ToUpper` will still happen though. When your client calls the web service, the data the WS returns will use the getter in your code. Unless you're calling the WS and getting this object, then repeatedly set and get that property, you shouldn't have any issues. The initial object returned should have `ToUpper` called.

Comment: @RyanP Very true, but I am trying to set the property in the client. What would be the cleanest approach to, I guess, duplicating the logic in the client?

Comment: Like Simon said, the client needs the classes. If these classes are meant to be shared, and it looks like they are, you should have these classes in a common assembly, and let both the client and the server reference them.

Comment: Got it. The problem I run into with that is since the class is generic, when the WCF service serializes the class, it creates classes for each generic used (TestGenericOfString), so even if the classes are shared, the client won't use the generic class. I apologize, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share the assembly by specifying it in svcutil when you generate your client code. The generic aspect shouldn't matter.

Check this link for an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19625/Sharing-Types-Between-WCF-Service-and-Client

Update:
You may also want to look into the KnownTypes attribute to tell the serializer which generic types it can expect.